# How to replace special characters with their equivalent in android?

Tags: android

While i'm retrieving data from remote server i'm getting some special
characters  when i get known special characters i replaced them
with their original characters but when i don't no the
special characters how can i replace them? Some of the special
characters are as follows..

```
&acirc; €œ €™ € €“ â; ' &amp; &euro; &uuml; &Uuml; &Ucirc; &Ugrave;
&ucirc; &ugrave; &Oslash; &szlig;
```

Above are some them like this i'm getting some other . How to replace
these with their original characters in android.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your question is how do you decode html encoded text?

```
Html.fromHtml(server_response).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Html.fromHtml(server_response).toString();
```

Comment: Why the need to add an identical answer almost two years later?